# How to configure NGINX server which download any files in derectory

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, nginx-location, winginx

I am  trying to configure NGINX server on Linux which downloads any files from the directory.

But the problem I am facing is when the file is a text file or the file name contains any special character like spaces and ( "()"#"&"  ) then the browser will not entertain and gives me nothing.

How do I solve this issue?
my Configuration is as fallows

```
http {
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile            on;
tcp_nopush          on;
tcp_nodelay         on;
keepalive_timeout   65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;

include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type        application/octet-stream;
#default_type        application/*;

# Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
# See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
# for more information.
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

index   index.html index.htm;

server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    location / {}
```

error_page 404 /404.html;
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;

Answer (score 2):

To download files rather than display them in the browser, the MIME type should be set to `application/octet-stream`. *Which is often declared as the default type anyway.*

Normally, `nginx` uses the file extension to determine which MIME type to use, but this can be turned off in a location by specifying the `types` directive with an empty set.

Filenames with strange characters can be accessed using %-encoded characters in the URL.

As an experiment, you might want to turn on `autoindex` and turn off `index` to browse the files. This will also show you that your difficult filenames can be downloaded too.

```
location / {
    index not_a_file;
    autoindex on;
    types {}
}
```

*Note: I am not aware of a mechanism to turn off `index`, other than setting it to an unlikely name. It is possible that the default `index.html` may not collide with the contents of your download directories.*

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types) for more.

Comment: What is _not_a_file_ ?

Comment: @dieter See the note in italics at the end of my answer.